# Instrument to make sphere in space

Tags: geometry, spheres, solid-geometry

I checked one of my old math books (for about $5$ years ago) and one of the problems is as follow:

$a)$ Why compass draw a circle?

$b)$ Can you give an example of an instrument to make sphere in space ?

Part $(a)$ is easy to answer. but I'm eager about knowing the answer of second part. I searched on internet but couldn't find such instrument.

Comment: A soap bubble blower?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Oh I see creative answers ;) thank you!

Comment: https://www.acorn-ind.co.uk/insight/the-science-experiment-which-took-off-like-a-rocket---creating-space-ball-bearings/

Answer (score 1):

Rotating a circle around its diameter produces a sphere.

If they want a physical device, a gyroscope can be pointed in any direction and spins.  An ice cream scoop carves out parts of a sphere.

Not sure what else they might be asking for.  It's not as if we have a 3d piece of paper to draw on.